# DHTMLX Gantt Chart Usage with Angular 2 Framework gives an error

Tags: angular-cli, dhtmlx

Did all step according to the tutorial given by DHTMLX. However getting error while init gantt:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import "dhtmlx-gantt";


@Component({
    selector: "gantt",
    styles: [
        `
        :host{
            display: block;
            height: 600px;
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
        }
    `],
    template: "<div #gantt_here style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>",
})
export class GanttComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("gantt_here") ganttContainer: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit(){
        gantt.init(this.ganttContainer.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Here is an error

> ERROR in src/app/views/tasks/gantt.component.ts(19,3): error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'gantt'.

I didn't find any difference between my and dowloaded project, which runs without any error. Link to git
https://github.com/DHTMLX/angular2-gantt-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding three lines of code in tsconfig.app.json file solves all problem

```
"types": [
    "dhtmlxgantt"
]
```

Comment: Adding it to "compilerOptions":{ "types": ["dhtmlxgantt"]} gets rid of the error, and webpack will start the server, but I still get "gantt" is not defined. Looking into this error.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for trial version is the following:

- Don't add the `.css` and `.js` in the `index.html` as I supposed it's suggested here: 
  https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__install_with_bower.html#addingprofessionaleditionintoproject. Add them in the `angular.json` instead.
- Snoop in the `package.json` file of the free `npm` installable version of `dhtmlx-gantt`
- Change the `package.json` of the trial version in order to 1) delete the reference to index.js, and 2) to add types. Mine looks like this:

```
    {
      "name": "dhtmlx-gantt-samples",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Simple backend and REST api for dhtmlx gantt samples",
      "main": "codebase/dhtmlxgantt.js",
      "types": "codebase/dhtmlxgantt.d.ts",
      "author": "DHTMLX",
      "license": "DHTMLX Evaluation License",
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "striptags": "^3.1.1"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While I was using this package for a project I was working on, I did have to do something a bit unusual with it

I added this line in my imports

```
import {} from '@types/dhtmlxgantt';
```

I think when they developed this chart, they didn't fully understand how types worked with TypeScript and how to package them up correctly.

I did find [this blog post](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/dhtmlx-gantt-chart-usage-angularjs-2-framework/) pretty helpful when it came to using this package. I ended up moving away from using this package and building my own custom gantt chart because their chart didn't have the functionality we needed for my project. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

import { gantt } from "dhtmlx-gantt";

rather than

import "dhtmlx-gantt";

seemed to work for me.